# Typing the first letter(s) of a variable to get quickly to that place in the Matlab Workspace

Tags: matlab, variables

WHen a list contains many items, it's very useful to get to the one you need by typing its first letter or first few letter. This works for instance in Windows Explorer and most modern user interfaces across platforms.

In the Matlab WOrkspace, this does not work, e.g. hitting 'x' will not take me to the first variable whose name starts with x. This means time wasted browsing through variables.
Is there a way to make such a feature work?

Comment: Not quite sure if there's a way to get that "jump to" functionality but you can open any variable using the `openvar()` function in the command window/script.

Comment: That along with the suggestion/autocomplete functionality of  `.mlx` live scripts are pretty good.

Comment: This sounds like a good feature request to send to MathWorks Tech Support (support@mathworks.com)!